# How to select some out of many nodes in XML along with the text or attribute values of that node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a complex XML , simplified version of which is given here. 
What I am trying to achieve is to get the data ( text or attribute values ) from only given set of nodes 
in an XML. Many examples are available only with XPATH. but my XML structure is complex and I wanted to use recursive method to scan through the nodes instead of hard coding XPATH.

**INPUT:**

```
<Root>
    <Book>
    <Content >
    <Chapter id="1" startpage="1" endpage="20">
        <Topic id="1">
        <Title>Title1</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
        <Topic id="1.1">
        <Title>Title1.1</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
        <Topic id="1.2">
        <Title>Title1.2</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
    </Chapter>
    <Chapter id="2" startpage="21" endpage="90">
        <Topic id="2">
        <Title>Title2</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
        <Topic id="2.1">
        <Title>Title2.1</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
        <Topic id="2.1.2">
        <Title>Title2.1.2</Title>
        <Content>Paragraphs</Content>
        </Topic>
    </Chapter>
    <Index>
    Some more nodes here
    </Index>
             </Content>
    </Book>
</Root>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
<Root>
<Book>
<Content>
    <Chapter id="1" startpage="1" endpage="20">

    <Title>Title1</Title>

    <Title>Title1.1</Title>

    <Title>Title1.2</Title>

    </Chapter>
<Chapter id="2" startpage="21" endpage="90">

    <Title>Title2</Title>

    <Title>Title2.1</Title>

    <Title>Title2.1.2</Title>

</Chapter>

</Book>
</Root>
```

**CURRENT XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <ns:WhiteList>
      <name>Root</name>
      <name>Book</name>
      <name>Chapter</name>
      <name>Title</name> 
   </ns:WhiteList>

   <xsl:variable name="whistList" select="document('')/*/ns:WhiteList" />

   <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:if test="attribute::*[name()=$whistList/*]">
         <xsl:copy/>

      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>   

     <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[name()=$whistList/*]">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:value-of select="node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
         </xsl:copy>

      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **only** determining factor is the node's name (regardless of the path to the node), you could try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="whiteList">
    <name>Root</name>
    <name>Book</name>
    <name>Chapter</name>
    <name>Title</name>
    <name>id</name>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="whiteListSet" select="exsl:node-set($whiteList)/name" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()=$whiteListSet">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="name()=$whiteListSet and name(parent::*)=$whiteListSet">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:if test="name(parent::*)=$whiteListSet">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When the above is applied to your example input, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <Book>
      <Chapter id="1">
         <Title>Title1</Title>
         <Title>Title1.1</Title>
         <Title>Title1.2</Title>
      </Chapter>
      <Chapter id="2">
         <Title>Title2</Title>
         <Title>Title2.1</Title>
         <Title>Title2.1.2</Title>
      </Chapter>
   </Book>
</Root>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your answer is accurate and is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

i have added the following to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="Topic">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

and the output now is

```
<Root>
   <Book>
      <Content>
         <Chapter>
            <id>1</id>
            <startpage>1</startpage>
            <endpage>20</endpage>
            <Title>Title1</Title>
            <Title>Title1.1</Title>
            <Title>Title1.2</Title>
         </Chapter>
         <Chapter>
            <id>2</id>
            <startpage>21</startpage>
            <endpage>90</endpage>
            <Title>Title2</Title>
            <Title>Title2.1</Title>
            <Title>Title2.1.2</Title>
         </Chapter>
      </Content>
   </Book>
</Root>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. As I mentioned this is just a simpler version of my XML. using XPATH in my actual XML will be very tricky as it is huge and has lot of nesting. So I am looking for better alternative for this.  One possible alternative is recursion.

Comment: @user3391883 Asking here is useless if you do not show the _actual_ XML you have as input. You just waste people's time because their solution is not going to work anyway. Please post the actual input XML, together with an accurate description of how it translates to your desired output. I am quite confident that you do not need recursion for this and that it would not be a viable solution.

Comment: My original XML is 37947 lines, I am sure stack overflow will not allow that big XML to be added as code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this one is working. However, it still shows the node which i dont want. I believe that is because of the node having an attribute in it.

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="some:ns">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <ns:WhiteList>
            <elename>Chapter</elename>
            <elename>Title</elename>
    </ns:WhiteList>
    <xsl:variable name="whistList" select="document('')/*/ns:WhiteList" />

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="flatattr"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*" name="flatattr">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::*[name()=$whistList/*]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Expression[ancestor::Expression]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SimpleExpression">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ValueExpression|Operator">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: and what is it that you don't want?

Comment: it still shows the node which contains nothing but either a child node or is empty. e..g in original xml book and content node. is there a way to elimiate them. I assume to preserve the structure XSL retains them